# How do I prevent immediate wake up from suspend and/or hibernation from PCI devices?

Tags: suspend, wakeup

For a few days, my Ubuntu 12.04 desktop computer has mysteriously been waking up immediately after going to suspend mode.

Since installation, my Ubuntu 12.10 laptop computer has also been resuming immediately after suspend and hibernation.

How to prevent those?

Related:

- [How to make this persist across reboots](https://askubuntu.com/q/152403/1004020)
- [Same question but for USB devices](https://askubuntu.com/q/848698/1004020)

Comment: I don't have the reputation to add a proper answer, but I managed to fix this simply by charging my laptop. I think Ubuntu automatically wakes up when the battery is low (which seems counter-intuitive). Obviously this won't fix any issues with a desktop, but it might be worth trying for anyone with this issue on a laptop

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This problem was probably caused by strange USB signals. `gedit /proc/acpi/wakeup` showed me, that wakeup was enabled for USB0 and USB2.

```
sudo -s
echo USB0 > /proc/acpi/wakeup
echo USB2 > /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

switched them to disabled *(checked by  `gedit /proc/acpi/wakeup` again or refreshing the file-view)*, and after that, the computer stays in suspend like it should. :-)

Comment: This solution did not work for me. PS2K was enabled (keyboard wakeup) but changing it made no difference.

Comment: In my case there were no USB* devices, looks like they were internally connected through USB-hub: adding EHC1, EHC2 and XHC to /proc/acpi/wakeup helped me.

Comment: In my case it was _XHCI_ for USB 3

Comment: @Bazon can you please have a look at `http://askubuntu.com/questions/852600/ubuntu-16-04-wakes-up-immediately-from-suspend-after-installing-fprint-in-lenovo` and help me to figure it out

Comment: For me disabling `IGBE` worked

Comment: For me it was GLAN (meant for wakeup from the physical network)

Comment: Using the same principle I had to disable my `NIC`.

Comment: for me it was OHC1 OHC2 and XHC that worked

Comment: they seemed to have re-enabled themselves. how do i make these changes permanent?

Answer (score 32):

I recently had the same symptom on Asus Zenbook Pro UX501 on Ubuntu 15.04.  Bazon's exact fix did not work but Vladimir Rutsky's variation did.  Specifically:

If running from the terminal `cat /proc/acpi/wakeup` shows the following lines

```
EHC1      S3    *enabled  pci:0000:00:xx.x
EHC2      S3    *enabled  pci:0000:00:xx.x
XHC       S3    *enabled  pci:0000:00:xx.x
```

(pci addresses may be different)

then toggle these three to disabled by issuing the following commands:

```
sudo -s
echo EHC1 > /proc/acpi/wakeup
echo EHC2 > /proc/acpi/wakeup
echo XHC > /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

Comment: Doing above didnot resolve my problem :(

Comment: For me disabling `IGBE` worked, above three didn't

Comment: @ilikerrobots This does not fix it permanently, how to fix it permanetly

Comment: GLAN quickly switches back to enabled. Any idea why?

Comment: To make it persist put it in a cron entry timed for `@reboot`. I found it useful to only run the echo if it was in fact enabled by putting a test in a shell script like so `egrep -q '^XHC1\s+S[0-9]\s+\*enabled' /proc/acpi/wakeup && echo XHC1 > /proc/acpi/wakeup` (my problem device was XHC1 - a USB chipset).

Comment: For me it was XHC

Answer (score 23):

If you know which device wake up your PC go to first step to follow the guide. If you don't, then open terminal and do:

```
cat /var/log/syslog
```

And find which device is waking your PC.

So now:

1. hit in terminal:

   ```
   grep . /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/wakeup
   ```

To list all usb ports that wakeup our pc.

```
sudo su
```

we have now root privillages.

2.I have 8 USB ports and in this example let's say that I want to disable usb8 ,so:

```
echo disabled > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb8/power/wakeup
```

Go ahead and test it. Now that specific device in USB port 8 won't wake up the PC.

Next step, to make the change permanent after each boot:

3.

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

And we paste the command from step 2. In there (before the exit 0 of course).

That's it.

***optional*** Only if after sleep/wakeup process the USB 8 device , in my example , revert back to enabled.

4. Write a `udev` rule too to execute the command after every boot,sleep,wake up.

Open a terminal and do:

```
lsusb
```

At your keyboard device id information the 4 first digits are the vendor id and the 4 next digits are the product id [image: screenshot]

Next do:

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/10-wakeup.rules
```

Where "wakeup" enter your desired name of the script. Number 10 is the priority in case you have many other udev rules, the lower the number the 'rule' will be executed before the others.

Copy paste this and replace the vendor id and product id with your own wireless keyboard vendor id and product id.

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="062a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="4101" RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo disabled > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb8/power/wakeup'"
```

***usb8** for me is my wireless keyboard (you can also see that in the screenshot (Bus 008)), replace it with your own.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to save , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit and reboot.

Comment: thanks! this looks interesting. would you mind adding your guide here (changing it so it addresses the specific issue of this question)

Comment: thanks. this is not quite what I wanted, but it got me to fix the issue - by modifying the rc.local file (my issue is not specific to the USB ports). I have posted my own solution, but you will get the bounty (I cannot award it before tomorrow though)

Comment: Which are safe to disable? Will I run into problem if I disable all? The only enabled is for me is /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-2/power/wakeup:enabled

Comment: syslog doesn't even mention what is waking up the computer

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on a ThinkPad P14s and this is the only solution that worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

**To make the fix permanent**

(I am compiling the solutions provided by Bazon, Ilikerobots, and Pavlos Theodorou - together they address my specific issue)

To fix the issue permanently, whether it is a USB port waking up the system or something else:

1. Find out what is allowed to wake up your system:

> gedit /proc/acpi/wakeup

You might get these or similar lines:

> EHC1      S3    *enabled  pci:0000:00:xx.x
>
> EHC2      S3    *enabled  pci:0000:00:xx.x
>
> XHC       S3    *enabled  pci:0000:00:xx.x

Then open:

> sudo gedit /etc/rc.local

and add these lines (or similar, depending on the results above) **before** `exit 0`

> echo EHC1 > /proc/acpi/wakeup
>
> echo EHC2 > /proc/acpi/wakeup
>
> echo XHC > /proc/acpi/wakeup

Comment: oh i didn't think about it. of course it could be another port besides a usb. i'm glad you solved it.

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me on my Mac Book Pro 2015

I added the following to `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/wakeup_disable`

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wakeup_disable
#
# Avoids that system wakes up immediately after suspend or hibernate
#
# Tested on MacBookPro 2015

case $1 in
  pre)
    if grep -qE '^XHC1.*enabled' /proc/acpi/wakeup; then
        echo XHC1 > /proc/acpi/wakeup
    fi
    if grep -qE '^LID0.*enabled' /proc/acpi/wakeup; then
        echo LID0 > /proc/acpi/wakeup
    fi
    ;;
esac
```

**Note** this will prevent waking up via the lid opening and via keyboard/mouse/USB device you have to push the power button.

References:

1. https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Apple/MacBookPro/Early-2015-13-inch#Immediate_wakeup_after_sleep
2. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MacBookPro11,x

Comment: Can't resist mentioning the [UUoC](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat) :-). But had you written `if grep -qE '^XHC1.*enabled' /proc/acpi/wakeup; then` instead, I would have missed an apportunity to comment...

Comment: I cannot believe I did that! Fixed it ;)

Comment: This answer makes way more sense than other "permanent fixes" I've seen, most of which don't check whether the problematic wakeup is enabled before trying to fix it.

Comment: In Linux Mint and my Thinkpad T480s, the cause is XHC, so I disable it and so far, my Thinkpad no longer wakeup by itself when lid closed

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in a simple way, writing the following lines in `/etc/rc.local` to enable only wakeup by PS2 keyboard:

```
for d in `cat /proc/acpi/wakeup |grep enabled|grep -v PS2K|cut -b -4`; do
    echo $d >/proc/acpi/wakeup ; 
done
```

When Linux boots, it executes the `/etc/rc.local` file disabling wakeup by USB or other devices.