# Toshiba resume automatically after suspending in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, power-management, bluetooth, suspend, toshiba

I have a Toshiba L845 and i when i suspend ubuntu it wake up 2 seconds later.
Here you are some info.

cat /proc/cmdline

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=80498f02-8962-4085-81f7-7e01fbc494fc ro quiet splash intel_pstate=enable vt.handoff=7
```

lspci -k | grep -iA2 VGA

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series]
Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Radeon HD 7670M
Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
```

cat /var/log/syslog | grep PM:

```
Jun 12 18:38:58 amrras-pc kernel: [ 8765.969162] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
Jun 12 18:38:58 amrras-pc kernel: [ 8766.110230] PM: Preparing system for mem sleep
Jun 12 18:38:58 amrras-pc kernel: [ 8766.113428] PM: Entering mem sleep
Jun 12 18:38:58 amrras-pc kernel: [ 8768.119383] PM: suspend of devices complete after 2009.020 msecs
Jun 12 18:38:58 amrras-pc kernel: [ 8768.119501] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 0.117 msecs
Jun 12 18:38:58 amrras-pc kernel: [ 8768.197198] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 77.819 msecs
Jun 12 18:38:58 amrras-pc kernel: [ 8768.197824] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
Jun 12 18:38:58 amrras-pc kernel: [ 8768.823061] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
Jun 12 18:38:58 amrras-pc kernel: [ 8769.069601] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 125.436 msecs
Jun 12 18:38:58 amrras-pc kernel: [ 8769.069725] PM: early resume of devices complete after 0.099 msecs
Jun 12 18:38:58 amrras-pc kernel: [ 8771.333504] PM: resume of devices complete after 2267.391 msecs
Jun 12 18:38:58 amrras-pc kernel: [ 8771.333680] PM: Finishing wakeup.
Jun 12 18:40:15 amrras-pc kernel: [ 8839.193188] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
Jun 12 18:40:15 amrras-pc kernel: [ 8839.378479] PM: Preparing system for mem sleep
Jun 12 18:40:15 amrras-pc kernel: [ 8839.381667] PM: Entering mem sleep
Jun 12 18:40:15 amrras-pc kernel: [ 8841.444678] PM: suspend of devices complete after 2064.091 msecs
Jun 12 18:40:15 amrras-pc kernel: [ 8841.444833] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 0.152 msecs
Jun 12 18:40:15 amrras-pc kernel: [ 8841.524584] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 79.797 msecs
Jun 12 18:40:15 amrras-pc kernel: [ 8841.525148] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
Jun 12 18:40:15 amrras-pc kernel: [ 8842.253549] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
Jun 12 18:40:15 amrras-pc kernel: [ 8842.501780] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 127.505 msecs
Jun 12 18:40:15 amrras-pc kernel: [ 8842.501902] PM: early resume of devices complete after 0.097 msecs
Jun 12 18:40:15 amrras-pc kernel: [ 8844.770332] PM: resume of devices complete after 2269.779 msecs
Jun 12 18:40:15 amrras-pc kernel: [ 8844.770548] PM: Finishing wakeup.
Jun 12 18:46:17 amrras-pc kernel: [ 9194.444252] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
Jun 12 18:46:17 amrras-pc kernel: [ 9194.616654] PM: Preparing system for mem sleep
Jun 12 18:46:17 amrras-pc kernel: [ 9194.619833] PM: Entering mem sleep
Jun 12 18:46:17 amrras-pc kernel: [ 9196.628265] PM: suspend of devices complete after 2010.496 msecs
Jun 12 18:46:17 amrras-pc kernel: [ 9196.628390] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 0.123 msecs
Jun 12 18:46:17 amrras-pc kernel: [ 9196.706763] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 78.457 msecs
Jun 12 18:46:17 amrras-pc kernel: [ 9196.707303] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
Jun 12 18:46:17 amrras-pc kernel: [ 9197.435387] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
Jun 12 18:46:17 amrras-pc kernel: [ 9197.683504] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 127.185 msecs
Jun 12 18:46:17 amrras-pc kernel: [ 9197.683623] PM: early resume of devices complete after 0.096 msecs
Jun 12 18:46:17 amrras-pc kernel: [ 9199.950284] PM: resume of devices complete after 2269.140 msecs
Jun 12 18:46:17 amrras-pc kernel: [ 9199.950520] PM: Finishing wakeup.
```

and last:

pastebinit /var/log/pm-suspend.log 
    [Link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7635847)

I found this behavior too:

In AC mode, if i disable Bluetooth the system suspends ok (i tried several times)
In Battery mode, it works always ok.

I really do not understand what is going on.

PD: Sorry for my english

Thanks

---

update!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Well, it seems that everything is random.
Then another thing i did was:

I realized that acpitool can change devices to not wake up from suspend (according to what I read)

Before

```
   Device   S-state   Status   Sysfs node
  ---------------------------------------
  1. P0P1     S4    *disabled
  2. GLAN     S0    *disabled
  3. EHC1     S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.0
  4. EHC2     S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1a.0
  5. XHC      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0
  6. HDEF     S0    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1b.0
  7. RP01     S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.0
  8. RP02     S4    *disabled
  9. PXSX     S4    *disabled
  10. FRES    S0    *disabled
  11. RP03    S0    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.2
  12. PXSX    S4    *disabled  pci:0000:08:00.0
  13. RP04    S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.3
  14. PXSX    S4    *enabled   pci:0000:09:00.0
  15. ATHE    S4    *disabled
  16. RP05    S4    *disabled
  17. PXSX    S4    *disabled
  18. RP06    S4    *disabled
  19. PXSX    S4    *disabled
  20. RP07    S4    *disabled
  21. PXSX    S4    *disabled
  22. RP08    S4    *disabled
  23. PXSX    S4    *disabled
  24. PEG0    S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:01.0
  25. PEGP    S4    *disabled
  26. PEG1    S4    *disabled
  27. PEG2    S4    *disabled
  28. PEG3    S4    *disabled
  29. LID     S4    *enabled
```

After this command:
acpitool -W 5

Using lspic i found that device 3,4,5 was: 
    00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
    00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
    00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)

```
   Device   S-state   Status   Sysfs node
  ---------------------------------------
  1. P0P1     S4    *disabled
  2. GLAN     S0    *disabled
  3. EHC1     S3    *disabled   pci:0000:00:1d.0
  4. EHC2     S3    *disabled   pci:0000:00:1a.0
  5. XHC      S3    *disabled  pci:0000:00:14.0
  6. HDEF     S0    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1b.0
  7. RP01     S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.0
  8. RP02     S4    *disabled
  9. PXSX     S4    *disabled
  10. FRES    S0    *disabled
  11. RP03    S0    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.2
  12. PXSX    S4    *disabled  pci:0000:08:00.0
  13. RP04    S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.3
  14. PXSX    S4    *enabled   pci:0000:09:00.0
  15. ATHE    S4    *disabled
  16. RP05    S4    *disabled
  17. PXSX    S4    *disabled
  18. RP06    S4    *disabled
  19. PXSX    S4    *disabled
  20. RP07    S4    *disabled
  21. PXSX    S4    *disabled
  22. RP08    S4    *disabled
  23. PXSX    S4    *disabled
  24. PEG0    S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:01.0
  25. PEGP    S4    *disabled
  26. PEG1    S4    *disabled
  27. PEG2    S4    *disabled
  28. PEG3    S4    *disabled
  29. LID     S4    *enabled
```

I do not like this solution but it is what i have for now.
I do not know how make this setting permanent because i lost changes after reboot. Any idea???
I'm afraid to have any side effect

Thanks again

Martin

Comment: _"I do not know how make this setting permanent because i lost changes after reboot. Any idea?"_ - See [How do I make changes to /proc/acpi/wakeup permanent?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/152403/how-do-i-make-changes-to-proc-acpi-wakeup-permanent)

Comment: This is a bug and you should report it on Launchpad. You will then be asked to [try the very latest mainline kernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds?action=show&redirect=KernelMainlineBuilds) to verify the bug has not already been fixed. If the bug still exists, you will be asked to follow the instructions at [DebuggingKernelSuspend](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend)