# Ubuntu 12.04 comes out of hibernate/standby randomly on Dell XPS 13

Tags: 12.04, laptop, power-management, suspend, hibernate

I have an ubuntu 12.04 laptop and it comes out of hibernate or standby randomly.

For example, yesterday I selected hibernate, closed the lid and put it in my computer bag.  24 hours later, it is still closed, in the bag, not doing anything. (I check it was there, not running, cold.  Six hours later it has come out of hibernation, has 3% battery left and has overheated to the point I can't recharge the battery. This has happened without opening the lid.

This has happened a few times before, where I put it on standby or hibernate, close the lid and I come to use it hours later and find it is running again even though the lid is still closed.

The only way to prevent this at the moment is to do a full shutdown.  Is there a way to prevent it coming out of hibernate or stand by spuriously.  Note: even if it does come out of hibernate it is set to hibernate after 30 minutes idle, which it doesn't do, it just runs until the battery is flat.

Comment: Maybe some hints in [Toshiba resume automatically after suspending in Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/482533/toshiba-resume-automatically-after-suspending-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: @bain +1 It looks similar, though it happens after hours on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Check `cat /sys/kernel/debug/wakeup_sources` for active_count and event_count, they should increase after a wakeup and the "name" column should tell you the source of the system wakeup event. `cat /proc/acpi/wakeup` will show you which devices are "enabled" to generate wakeup events. `find /sys/devices -name wakeup` will show you all nodes for wakeup control, you can `cat` those to see the current setting or echo "enabled"/"disabled" to turn wakeup on or off for that device.

Comment: What type of laptop is this? Apparently there is a bug/"feature" in the Lenovo BIOS that wakes the system after 3 hours: [Ubuntu 14.04 wakes from suspend by itself](http://askubuntu.com/questions/502381/ubuntu-14-04-wakes-from-suspend-by-itself?rq=1)

Comment: It is a Dell XPS 13 ultra book.  For the most part it is really useful, unless I forget to shut it down e.g. it hibernates itself, I forget it might just start up again and drain the battery.  I could disable the self hibernate and remove the option.  Your suggestions are useful, but I haven't been able to try it yet.

Comment: Is there any harm is disabling wake up for all devices?

Comment: If you do that you probably won't be able to wake up the laptop. Best to leave at least one wakeup option, LID0 would be a good choice if that works. It might also be the case that the wakeup is something the BIOS is doing and Linux is not responsible.

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly [bug #1161962 - XPS 13 wakes up from suspend spontaneously](https://bugs.launchpad.net/dell-sputnik/+bug/1161962) or some other related bug.

This is a bug and should be reported it on Launchpad. You will then be asked to:

- Update all of your packages (`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`)
- [Upgrade your BIOS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BiosUpdate) if an upgrade is available.
- [Try the very latest mainline kernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds?action=show&redirect=KernelMainlineBuilds) to verify the bug has not already been fixed.
- Follow the instructions at [DebuggingKernelSuspend](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend).

Even if the bug is fixed in later mainline Linux kernels, it is still important to report the issue on Launchpad to ensure that the bug gets fixed in the Ubuntu kernel.