# Ubuntu 12.04 Lts drains battery overnight during hibernation

Tags: 12.04

I have 12.04 current installed on my laptop. First thing, the wifi gets hard blocked when enters suspend. This kept me away from Ubuntu. Well, this isn't the matter right now. I started using the hibernation as it kept my wifi alive but I've noticed that my battery drains a lot faster than suspend while on hibernation. It drained overnight and I saw it in sleep mode when I woke up. It bugs me a lot, so any solutions????

Edit: I found out it doesn't hibernate at all. It just keeps running.

Comment: A laptop does not usually consume any power when hibernated. And you sure it is not coming out of hibernate? Like [this question - "Ubuntu comes out of hibernate/stand by randomly"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/504256/ubuntu-comes-out-of-hibernate-stand-by-randomly)? Or perhaps coming out of hibernate, then automatically hibernating again? Are you sure the laptop is really hibernating and not suspending?

Comment: If it suspends, then the wifi gets hard blocked. That does not happen in hibernation.

Comment: It happens exactly like the question in the link

Comment: So it randomly comes out of hibernation?

Comment: I don't think so....

Comment: How are you hibernating it?

Comment: I have installed the Gnome 3 environment. I just tweaked it to 'Close Lid: Hibernate'