# Upgraded Ubuntu 16.04 sometimes fails to sleep

Tags: xubuntu, suspend, power-management, 16.04, xfce4-power-manager

I upgraded my system from 15.10 (Ubuntu + xfce = XUbuntu) to 16.04 and afterwards it happens 50% that when I send system to Sleep through "start menu > turn off > sleep" that screens go blank and hardware keeps running (I hear fans are turning). I can't change to console (ctrl + alt + f2) or do anything else. I'm looking for way how to trace this problem down. I did not find anytihng in following logs:

**/var/log/syslog.1**

```
May  1 01:05:01 lampa CRON[7380]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
May  1 01:14:27 lampa NetworkManager[884]: <info>  [1462058067.4749] manager: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
May  1 01:14:27 lampa NetworkManager[884]: <info>  [1462058067.4749] manager: sleeping...
May  1 01:14:27 lampa whoopsie[796]: [01:14:27] offline
May  1 01:14:27 lampa NetworkManager[884]: <info>  [1462058067.4750] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
May  1 01:14:27 lampa systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
May  1 01:14:27 lampa systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
May  1 01:14:27 lampa systemd-sleep[7497]: Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (nil)  error: No such file or directory
May  1 01:14:27 lampa systemd-sleep[7499]: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant failed with error code 255.
May  1 01:14:27 lampa systemd-sleep[7497]: Suspending system...
```

**/var/log/pm-suspend.log.1**

Last line is too old, from: Tue Apr 26 19:44:13 CEST 2016: Finished. File 'pm-suspend.log' is empty.

**/var/log/kern.log**

```
...
Apr 30 21:26:34 lampa kernel: [ 8420.249061] Key type cifs.idmap registered
May  1 01:14:27 lampa NetworkManager[884]: <info>  [1462058067.4749] manager: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
May  1 01:14:27 lampa NetworkManager[884]: <info>  [1462058067.4749] manager: sleeping...
May  1 01:14:27 lampa NetworkManager[884]: <info>  [1462058067.4750] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
May  1 08:01:21 lampa kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
...
```

I was looking for a Xorg log, but I don't know which log lines belong to this moment in time. When I lookged on it by file date (files Xorg.0.log and Xorg.0.log.old) these files are quite short and without errors, they end up with:

```
[    11.084] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    12.912] (II) RADEON(0): Allocate new frame buffer 2048x768 stride 2048
[    12.912] (II) RADEON(0): VRAM usage limit set to 931309K
[  1258.032] (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
[  1259.227] (II) AIGLX: Resuming AIGLX clients after VT switch
```

and

```
[    10.176] (II) RADEON(0): Allocate new frame buffer 2048x768 stride 2048
[    10.176] (II) RADEON(0): VRAM usage limit set to 931309K
```

**dmesg**

I can't find dmesg.0 on my system, I see only 'dmesg' and it is empty.

Where to look next?

Edit:
I found that it happends only after I run 'wine emulator with battle.net a game StarCraft 2'. I tried to kill all those processes that spawn and remain after I play the game. I'm wondering if my graphic card does not switch to some mode that can't sleep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely experiencing [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1574125).

To fix, try installing a new kernel.

> Commands for 64 bit system:
>
> ```
> cd /tmp
>
> wget \
> kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5.2-wily/linux-headers-4.5.2-040502_4.5.2-040502.201604200335_all.deb \
> kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5.2-wily/linux-headers-4.5.2-040502-generic_4.5.2-040502.201604200335_amd64.deb \
> kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5.2-wily/linux-image-4.5.2-040502-generic_4.5.2-040502.201604200335_amd64.deb
>
> sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.5*.deb linux-image-4.5*.deb
> ```

<sub>source:
Padraig Galvin, [bug report comment #26](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1574125/comments/26)</sub>

Comment: Exactly. I have core 4.4.0-21. Fixed by rebooting into older available core (in my case '4.2.0-30').

Answer (score 4):

I still have this problem, but have tested many possible fixes. The essence of the problem is that the suspend job fails, hangs.

I've tried [fishing through kernel logs line by line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/856599/suspend-wakes-up-immediately-can-you-read-this-kernel-log-for-me), still don't know for sure what is causing this. I thought problem was video, but now suspect it is network and/or USB-C support.

When the suspend fails, log in again, open a terminal. If in ps aux output, you see something like this, then you are in same situation.

```
$ ps aux | grep sus
root     22926  0.0  0.0   8668   840 ?        Ss   23:07   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-sleep suspend
```

That job, 22926, can be killed, which will cause the PC to suspend immediately.

```
$ sudo kill -9 22926
```

This week, I've found a pretty good way to avoid this.  Create a script file like this:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager stop
sudo /etc/init.d/networking stop
sudo systemctl suspend
```

For me, this reduces the delay when suspending and it has never failed yet

When you restart, you need to remember to re-start network manually.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager stop
sudo /etc/init.d/networking stop
sudo /etc/init.d/networking start
sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager start
```

This again tells network to close down, just for fun, and restarts it.

This is a high level solution. I've been into the weeds, changing lots of details within suspend scripts.  Nothing has worked as well as this.

The other interesting thread I found on this was that the hardware devices are malfunctioning and causing a false wakeup.  I tried that, but no benefit.  I do not think the suspend job would still be failed if this were the real issue.

Quite a few people have this same problem, seems like there might be many possible causes. Check out [this Ask Ubuntu search](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=%5Bsuspend%5D%20wakes%20up%20immediately). Some of my favorites:

- [16.04 - systemd suspends system but upon resume kernel then enters sleep and wake-up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/828486/systemd-suspends-system-but-upon-resume-kernel-then-enters-sleep-and-wake-up)
- [laptop fails to suspend or hibernate (wakes up after 2-5 seconds without user interaction)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449871/laptop-fails-to-suspend-or-hibernate-wakes-up-after-2-5-seconds-without-user-in)
- [Immediate wake up from suspend caused by USB 3.0 devices](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545071/immediate-wake-up-from-suspend-caused-by-usb-3-0-devices)
- [wakeup - How do I prevent immediate wake up from suspend and/or hibernation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148481/how-do-i-prevent-immediate-wake-up-from-suspend-and-or-hibernation)
- [14.04 - Ubuntu wakes up after few seconds of sleep](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598236/ubuntu-wakes-up-after-few-seconds-of-sleep)

Comment: Which version of kernel do you have? (you can find it out by "uname -a"), maybe you have also bugged 4.4.0-21?

Comment: After several months, I still have this problem, using all kinds of kernels... Linux delllap-16 4.8.0-32-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 13 14:30:43 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Can't believe your lengthy research efforts had no up-votes. +1 and well done.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (Xubuntu 16.04):

```
sudo apt-get remove light-locker
sudo apt-get install xscreensaver
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer and add how exactly you did it ?

Comment: This would not help me because I was already using xscreensaver instead of light-locker. I did that change it before the problem.

Comment: This one solves the "I can't see my cursor after a suspend and resume cycle".  It doesn't affect the problem that there hung program.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

```
Sep 26 17:26:15 pavel-kjsdfk systemd-sleep[8022]: Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (nil)  error: No such file or directory
Sep 26 17:26:15 pavel-kjsdfk systemd-sleep[8023]: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant failed with error code 255.
```

So, I was searching for any solutions about all day and nothing has helped me.
Then I found a questionable solution, but it works!

Open `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant`

Remove `/sbin/wpa_cli` and `resume` from the file such that:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

if [ "$2" = "suspend" ] || [ "$2" = "hybrid-sleep" ]; then
    case "$1" in
        pre) /sbin/wpa_cli suspend ;;
        post) /sbin/wpa_cli resume ;;
    esac
fi
```

becomes:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

if [ "$2" = "suspend" ] || [ "$2" = "hybrid-sleep" ]; then
    case "$1" in
        pre) suspend ;;
        post) ;;
    esac
fi
```