# Ubuntu 16.04 immediatly wake up on the Grub after hibernate

Tags: suspend, hibernate

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 (dualboot with Windows) on HP Spectre 13.

I launch hibernate in the terminal (sudo hibernate), it shut down then it automatically wake-up after 1 sec on the Grub interface. So I press the power button at this moment and it's ok, I can wake up later without problem. It is not convenient...

I already followed instructions from similar topics and I disabled all items in /proc/acpi/wakeup (only PWB is enabled).  The problem is still here.

- [How do I prevent immediate wake up from suspend and/or hibernation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148481/how-do-i-prevent-immediate-wake-up-from-suspend-and-or-hibernation)
- [Immediate wake up from suspend caused by USB 3.0 devices](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545071/immediate-wake-up-from-suspend-caused-by-usb-3-0-devices?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [laptop fails to suspend or hibernate (wakes up after 2-5 seconds without user interaction)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449871/laptop-fails-to-suspend-or-hibernate-wakes-up-after-2-5-seconds-without-user-in)

I noticed that some usb-hub or device still appear in notification (saying I can uplugged them) even they have not been physically plugged before. I guess it could be linked to my problem but I don't know how to investigate.

Any idea or command to solve it?

Thanks !