# Suspend issue on kernel 5.0

Tags: kernel, suspend, power-management, acpi

So recently I've been having issues with suspend on both of my ubuntu machines but the laptop is more important so I'll start there. My laptop on 18.04.2 recently got an update for kernel 5.0.0-23. Once updated the machine worked fine until I closed the lid. I noticed that the laptop wasn't suspending. I checked all the normal suspects.

I tried `systemctl suspend` and the screen goes blank but the power light stays lit where it would normally blink when sleeping. I am unable to get the system to come back on unless I hit the power button. When I check `dmesg` I find "PM: suspend entry (s2idle)".

This is odd because `cat /sys/power/mem_sleep` returns "s2idle [deep]"

Meanwhile if I attempt `sudo pm-suspend` the screen goes out and almost immediately turns back on. In this case `dmesg` reports "PM: suspend entry (deep)" but it jumps right to "PM: Syncing filesystems" and goes from there.

I've tried disabling all enabled devices with `/proc/acpi/wakeup` and messing with the power settings in gnome settings to no avail. Meanwhile if I boot up the last 4.18 kernel the laptop will suspend without any issues.

Any ideas as to what could be going on or any other information I could provide?
Thank you.

Comment: You can always switch to initial 4.15 kernel from the hwe "rolling" kernel. It will get updates till 18.04 EoL. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: Perhaps there is a solution here https://askubuntu.com/q/545071/881336