# Ubuntu 15.04 Suspend doesn't run `pm-suspend`

Tags: suspend, 15.04, backlight, systemd, pm-utils

After upgrading to Ubuntu GNOME 15.04 (from 14.10), I noticed my `pm-utils` hooks in `/etc/pm/sleep.d` aren't running anymore on suspend/resume.

I have a custom script which saves the brightness before suspend and restores it after resume. If I manually run `sudo pm-suspend` the hooks execute but if I close the laptop's lid (which suspends Ubuntu) the scripts aren't executed. Am I missing something?

The brightness script in /etc/pm/sleep.d is (worked on 14.04 and 14.10):

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in
    suspend|suspend_hybrid|hibernate)
        cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness > /tmp/.brightness_level
        # modprobe -r nvidiabl
        ;;
    resume|thaw)
        # modprobe nvidiabl
        cat /tmp/.brightness_level > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
        rm /tmp/.brightness_level
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: The script isn't relevant to the question itself but I added it in my edited comment

Comment: Turns out 15.04 uses `systemd` and not `upstart` which doesn't call pm-utils suspend/resume hooks. Posted my solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update**: Found a nicer solution using `systemd` with no external scripts. Create and enable the following service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Save brightness on suspend
DefaultDependencies=no
RequiresMountsFor=/var/lib/systemd/backlight
Before=sleep.target
StopWhenUnneeded=yes

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-backlight save acpi_video0
ExecStop=/lib/systemd/systemd-backlight load acpi_video0
TimeoutSec=90s

[Install]
WantedBy=sleep.target
```

**Ubuntu 16.04 Note**: The target backlight device name should be prefixed with "backlight:" (e.g. `backlight:acpi_video0`).

Enable by executing: `systemctl enable suspend-save-backlight.service` (or whatever you call it). Note that acpi_video0 is the name of the backlight symlink in `/sys/class/backlight` which is used to control the display brightness, might vary on different systems.

The above uses systemd's `systemd-backlight` executable to save and load the brightness before suspend and after resume respectively (inspired from `/lib/systemd/system/systemd-backlight@.service` which saves/loads brightness on restart/boot).

---

**Old Solution** (links a `systemd` service to my pm-utils suspend hook)

Found the problem. According to [this ArchWiki article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management#Sleep_hooks):

> systemd does not use pm-utils to put the machine to sleep when using systemctl suspend, systemctl hibernate or systemctl hybrid-sleep; pm-utils hooks, including any [custom hooks](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pm-utils#Creating_your_own_hooks), will not be run. However, systemd provides two similar mechanisms to run custom scripts on these events.

So the right way to do it with `systemd` (which is used by default in 15.04) is to create the following service files which execute my brightness control script in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/` as follows:

1. `/etc/systemd/system/root-suspend.service`:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Local system suspend actions
   Before=sleep.target

   [Service]
   Type=simple
   ExecStart=-/etc/pm/sleep.d/nvidiabl_brightness suspend

   [Install]
   WantedBy=sleep.target
   ```
2. `/etc/systemd/system/root-resume.service`:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Local system resume actions
   After=suspend.target

   [Service]
   Type=simple
   ExecStart=-/etc/pm/sleep.d/nvidiabl_brightness resume

   [Install]
   WantedBy=suspend.target
   ```

Then run the following to enable these services:

```
systemctl enable root-suspend.service
systemctl enable root-resume.service
```

Refer to the linked article for more details.

Comment: no there is no need to because systemd has alredy a service called systemd-backlight@.service that saves automatically the brightness of screen on shutdown

Comment: @solsTiCe My case isn't about shutdown, it's about suspend/resume