# Network manager must be restarted after wakeup in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, 15.04, restart

Upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to 15.04 on my lenovo T410 a couple of weeks ago and I have been having some problems with my network connection ever since.

Everything worked fine with 14.04, but now I am forced to run 'sudo service network-manager restart' almost every time my computer wakes up. 
It claims to be connected and it seems to have an IP, but i cant even access my routers GUI.
Any permanent solutions out there or anyone with similar problems?
It doesnt bother me to run the network-manager restart, except it sucks to do it every time im going to use my computer.

Comment: It is a known bug. There is a workaround to setup that restart in a script, but did not work for me well either. This happens only with some computers, not all.

Comment: use `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service` now on 15.04 instead of the old way with upstart.

Comment: @Pilot6, if it is a known bug, do you have a link to the bug tracking where it has been reported?

Answer (score 3):

You need to mess with **systemd** service and target.

Create a file `nm-resume.service` in `/etc/systemd/system/suspend.target.wants`

with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Restart NetworkManager at resume
After=suspend.target
After=hibernate.target
After=hybrid-sleep.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/systemctl --no-block restart NetworkManager.service

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
WantedBy=hibernate.target
WantedBy=hybrid-sleep.target
```

This needs to be tweaked or debugged but that's the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could automate the process by using pm-utils as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226278/run-script-on-wakeup).
The script can look like this and needs to be put in `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d`. Call it `99zzzMyScript` as it will be executed last.

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in
  hibernate)
    # put commands to run on hibernation here
    ;;
  thaw)
    # put commands to run when returning from hibernation here
    ;;
  suspend)
    # put commands to run on suspend here
    ;;
  resume) 
    # put commands to run when returning from suspension
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Does pm-utils is even used with `systemctl` now in 15.04 ??

Comment: According to this http://askubuntu.com/questions/620494/ubuntu-15-04-suspend-doesnt-run-pm-suspend it's not. I can't test it at the moment but perhaps it is worth to try.