# 15.04 suspend script not running and needs sudo privilege for modprobe MythTV

Tags: 15.04, scripts, suspend, mythtv

I'm running 15.04 along with MythTV.  The computer can suspend but freezes on resume.  I've traced this down to a problem with mythbackend and module saa7164.  I've written a script that I can manually run that will kill mythbackend and then unload module saa7164.  The script needs sudo privileges to modprobe saa7164.  I've also written a script that reloads module saa7164 and then resumes mythbackend.  When I do things manually I can run the first script, then suspend, then resume, run the second script, and everything works fine.

My problem is I want these to run on suspend/resume automatically and not prompt for a password.  I've tried every solution that I could find.  I've placed test scripts in /etc/pm/sleep.d and tried the solution posted in this link as well:

[Ubuntu 15.04 Suspend doesn't run `pm-suspend`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/620494/ubuntu-15-04-suspend-doesnt-run-pm-suspend)

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE THIS IS NOT MY FIX AND WAS SIMPLY A RE-DIRECT. I AM NOT AT ALL IMPLYING THIS IS A DUPLICATE, BUT THE FIX HAS MULTIPLE USES. THIS FIX WAS TAKEN FROM** [HERE:](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147241/execute-sudo-without-password)

The approach to solve your problem is to put your user in sudoers file, like you can see.

Open terminal window and type:

```
sudo visudo
```

In the bottom of the file, type the follow:

```
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Where username is your username in your system.
Save and close sudoers file (if you haven't changed your default terminal editor (you'll know if you have), press ctl+x to exit `nano` (but note that the screenshot below shows `vim`), and it'll prompt you to save).

[image]

After this, you can, in terminal window, type `sudo <Whatever you want>`, without being prompted for the password.

This only applies, to `sudo` command in terminal window.
For example, when you try to install a package in software center, you will be prompted to insert your password, like you can see in the next Screenshot.

[image]

I think this is what you want.