# Suspend instantly restarting - editing acpi/wakeup with systemd service

Tags: 18.04, systemd, acpi, wakeup

My 18.04 Ubuntu Ryzen desktop will wake itself up instantly after it suspends. I've tracked the problem down to /proc/acpi/wakeup
In the list of enabled services there are two services (labeled for what it's worth: AS43 and PTXH) which I can disable using the following shell commands:

```
sudo -s 
echo AS43 > /proc/acpi/wakeup
echo PTXH > /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

Once this is done - system wakes from sleep only from keyboard input - all is good. 
However I can't seem to automate this process.

One solution (and I'm open to others) is to make a service, /etc/systemd/system/suspendfix.service such as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=fix to prevent system from waking immediately after suspend

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c '/bin/echo GPP2 > /proc/acpi/wakeup'
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/bin/echo AS43 > /proc/acpi/wakeup'
ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c '/bin/echo PTXH > /proc/acpi/wakeup'
RemainAfterExit=yes
TimeoutSec=90s

[Install]
WantedBy=sleep.target
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

BUT this doesn't seem to work. Either my service script is incorrect or something is flipping the offending AS43 and PTXH back to enabled regardless of this systemd service file. Any help, much obliged! 
~
~

Comment: Might be related to this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1574120

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make changes to /proc/acpi/wakeup permanent?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152403/how-do-i-make-changes-to-proc-acpi-wakeup-permanent)

Answer (score 5):

Same issue (USB rewaking) on my Lenovo Yoga 910. solved with the [solution of mike-g2 (mikeg-utk)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1574120/comments/125):

1. Create file: `/etc/systemd/system/toggle.XHC.to.fix.suspend.issue.service`
   with following content:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description="Make suspend ignore USB wake up."

   [Service]
   ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "echo XHC >> /proc/acpi/wakeup"

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```
2. Create symbolic link to above script in /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/

   ```
   ln -s /etc/systemd/system/toggle.XHC.to.fix.suspend.issue.service /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/
   ```
3. Start service

   ```
   sudo systemctl daemon-reload
   sudo systemctl start toggle.XHC.to.fix.suspend.issue.service
   ```
4. Check if service was started

   ```
   sudo systemctl status toggle.XHC.to.fix.suspend.issue.service
   ```
5. Enable it on boot

   ```
   sudo systemctl enable toggle.XHC.to.fix.suspend.issue.service
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a Ryzen 2600 and Ubuntu 18.04.

Your script was very helpful.
To execute it on startup I added your lines

```
echo AS43 > /proc/acpi/wakeup
echo PTXH > /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

to a `/etc/rc.local` file.

Then I added a systemd service to start this script. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/how-to-enable-etcrc-local-with-systemd).

Thanks for finding the wakeup triggers!