# Why does my computer start by itself when I open it?

Tags: power-management, 18.10, bug-reporting

I installed ubuntu 18.10, for a while my pc turns on automatically when I open it, at first it didn't do that so I had to press the start button to turn it on. Note that I regularly update the system and also when I turn off the PC and do not close it it does not turn on automatically. Is it a bug? How to fix it? Or is it a new feature?

Comment: This has been answered. Have a look at: [UnderstandingSuspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049178/suspend-instantly-restarting-editing-acpi-wakeup-with-systemd-service)

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it a bug?

Unlikely. Well it could have been a bug that got fixed and made it working on your machine.

> Or is it a new feature?

No. It has been around for a while: I would assume it is the "wake on lid-open" feature some computers have. It is a setting in the BIOS. Maybe you inadvertently activated it?

Random example from the web:

[image]

Comment: I went through my bios and I didn't find the "wake on lid-open" feature.