# ACPI wakeup script to keep LID0 enabled on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: bash, scripts, macbook-pro, acpi, wakeup

I'm on Ubuntu 20.10. It runs on a macbook pro mid 2012.
It is running very well, but I still have a small issue with power management. When I close the lid, the macbook suspends. But when I open it, it does not wake up.
I do know that I can set LID0 and XHC1 with an echo to /proc/acpi/wakeup. When you echo these, then it is switched. So possibly I switch it off while I want it to have enabled.
Therefor I've found a script on askubuntu, that works well with 1 device, but not with 2. But the script was made for more then one device.

This is the original script:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a devices=("EHC1 EHC2 XHCI") # <-- Add your entries here
for device in "${devices[@]}"; do
    if grep -qw ^$device.*enabled /proc/acpi/wakeup; then
        sudo sh -c "echo $device > /proc/acpi/wakeup"
    fi
done
```

Made, or reposted by a user: Hrishikesh Kadam on: [AskUbuntu][1].

In: "cat /proc/acpi/wakeup" these are the XHC1 and LID0 items:

```
XHC1      S3    *disabled   pci:0000:00:14.0 
LID0      S4    *disabled  platform:PNP0C0D:00
```

I changed the script that I've found like this:

````
declare -a devices=("XHC1 LID0")
for device in "${devices[@]}"; do
    if grep -qw ^$device.*disabled /proc/acpi/wakeup; then
        sudo sh -c "echo $device > /proc/acpi/wakeup"
    fi
done ```

Which does not look wrong to me. But than I get this error: 

    grep: LID0.*disabled: File or folder does not exist

When I change the code like this: 

    declare -a devices=("XHC1")
so by removing 1 device, then the code works.

Why does this not work anymore? What changed in the way this is working? And how do I fix this script for Ubuntu 20.10? Please advise.
Anyone? 


  [1]: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1146264/apply-the-proc-acpi-wakeup-settings-permanently/1331422#1331422
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make changes to /proc/acpi/wakeup permanent?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152403/how-do-i-make-changes-to-proc-acpi-wakeup-permanent)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I've found the solution by removing the quotes from the line:
declare -a devices=("XHC1 LID0")

Then my script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a devices=( LID0 XHC1 )
for device in "${devices[@]}"; do
    if grep -qw ^$device.*disabled /proc/acpi/wakeup; then
        sudo sh -c "echo $device > /proc/acpi/wakeup"
    fi
done
```

In this way it is working. Is it that easy?