# How to change S-state in /proc/acpi/wakeup?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is there any way to change the power button S-state from S4 to S3 in `/proc/acpi/wakeup`:

```
CNVW      S4    *disabled
AWAC      S4    *disabled  platform:ACPI000E:00
PWRB      S4    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0C:00
```

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/152403/how-do-i-make-changes-to-proc-acpi-wakeup-permanent

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make changes to /proc/acpi/wakeup permanent?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152403/how-do-i-make-changes-to-proc-acpi-wakeup-permanent)