# Hibernation does not work in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, hibernate

When I enter `sudo pm-hibernate` in a terminal, it only turns the screen off for a small moment and immediately turns it on and then terminal goes to another blank line. (`pm-hibernate`will be finished)

Also it should noted that execution of `sudo pm-is-supported` has no output.

When I was using Ubuntu 14.04 and 14.10, this command was working fine. But in 15.04 it has stopped working.

More information:

- I'm currently using Ubuntu 15.04 - 64bit
- `pm-suspend` does work. `pm-suspend-hybrid` does NOT work. (exactly same effect of hibernate)
- I've enough disk space to save system state.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/148481/how-do-i-prevent-immediate-wake-up-from-suspend-and-or-hibernation

Answer (score 1):

The observation *"it only turns the screen off for a small moment and immediately turns it on"* suggests that it tries to hibernate, but is unsuccessful. The same thing happened with me due to some wake up event created by device.

Check the output of dmesg to find any logs related to pm. You can use this command to filter pm errors:

```
dmesg | tail -200 | grep pm
```

Have a close look at them, maybe one of them is the cause for hibernation not working. Hope this helps, do ask further if necessary.

Comment: I've found the problem, this is because my computer does not have a swap partition. Anyway, thanks for such interesting command.