# Laptop wake up from suspend when lid is closed

Tags: 15.04, suspend, power-management

I have installed on my laptop Ubuntu 15.04. Today I have closed the lid, the laptop got into suspend mode and I put my laptop in my bag. After 3 hours I  got him out and it was hot as hell! The laptop woke up from suspend by itself and continued to work while was in my backpack. What I can do to prevent this kind of problems?

Comment: Maybe you'll find this post useful http://askubuntu.com/questions/148481/how-do-i-prevent-immediate-wake-up-from-suspend-and-or-hibernation

Comment: Thanks, I will try that solution. Hope it will fix this :)