# Ubuntu wakes up immediately after suspend when USB mouse is connected

Tags: usb, suspend, wakeup

I have the problem that my Ubuntu wakes up immediately after suspend, not every time, but when I connect my USB 3.0 mouse.

When I start Ubuntu, it doesn't detect my mouse, so I must plug/unplug it few times, maybe suspend Ubuntu and wake it up. But when mouse is connected and works, then suspend doesn't work.

I tried editing the wakeup file and disabling some S3 lines, but after that, when I suspended Ubuntu, it turned off the screen, but the PC was still running, so it seems that isn't the right way to handle it.

How can I fix this properly?

Comment: For USB related wake up issues see this popular post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/148481/how-do-i-prevent-immediate-wake-up-from-suspend-and-or-hibernation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem happens on my Ubuntu system as well.  When it does, log in again, open a terminal, and run

```
$ ps aux | grep suspend
```

If you have the same problem I do, you will see a failed/hanging suspend process. That's what causes the system to start right again, because the suspend isn't finishing itself.

If in the same terminal you try this

```
$ sudo /sbin/shutdown -h now
```

you will get a refusal from the system, with a message saying something like that's a destructive transaction, that's the system d's way of saying that as long as that suspend process is hung, you aren't shutting down.

The only fix I know of is to kill the suspend process

```
$ kill -9 nnnnnn
```

where `nnnnnn` is the number of the hanging suspend process you see in the `ps aux` output.

I tried to track discussion of this in forums on the kernel and drivers, but it is pretty tough going.  Some people claim it is being solved by kernel updates, say into the latest `4.6` and `4.8` editions, but I don't see any benefit.  My problem, I'm pretty sure, links back to commercial Nvidia drivers that don't always get out of the way.

Comment: Problem happened today after activating nVidia 384.130 (previously under Intel iGPU only). However there is no hanging suspend process to kill. I did notice in `journalctl` ACPI is finishing resume just as `systemd` is starting the suspend process. Still +1 for good answer.

Answer (score 17):

I was having a similar issue to this one. Apparently, there's a known bug where the bluetooth service is causing Ubuntu to wake up immediately upon suspending https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1774994

This was the first link I found when I was googling an answer, which is why I'm posting this solution here.

The solution is basically to have a script ran before and after suspending to start and stop the bluetooth service.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Makes sure bluetooth service is not running while suspended.

if [ "${1}" == "pre" ]; then
    service bluetooth stop
elif [ "${1}" == "post" ]; then
    service bluetooth start
fi
```

Save this script as `bluetooth-suspend` under `/lib/systemd/system-sleep` and make sure the script can be executed with `chmod +x bluetooth-suspend`.

That seemed to fix the issue for me.

Comment: My keyboard is Bluetooth, this solved my wakeup issue.

Comment: I started having this problem about a week ago and this answer solved it for me, thanks.

Comment: I run Ubuntu 18.04 on an HP ProBook 440 G6, and I use a Logitech BT mouse. This fixed it for me as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Had this issue and I struggled to to find the source for a few days. My solution was to first search the log `journalctl -b | grep suspend`

I found the following:

```
PM: Device 0000:05:00.0 failed to suspend async: error 1
```

This line provided the device address that created this issue Than I used `lspci` to identify the device

```
05:00.0 ASmedia usb 3.1
```

Using `lspci` shows the actual names of devices by address and in my case I remember seeing this on my ASRock Bios so I rebooted and disabled support for ASmedia usb 3.1 and my Desktop suspended successfully.

My case is unique to me but might help others identify the issue.

Comment: I had a different issue, but this helped me find what was going wrong, thx!

Answer (score 1):

It happened to my computer when I used Microsoft Mouse. Before I had used Logitech mouse, then it worked  just fine. So I switched back to Logitech one, now it works normally again. I put computer on suspend, it stays.

Comment: This isn't a guaranteed answer. A) You don't know if OP problem is with a Microsoft Mouse. B) You don't know if OP has a Logitech mouse to plug in instead. C) It could very well be the OP already has a Logitech mouse and the suspend problem is still happening.

Comment: I found that if I unplug my iHaper C002 USB-C hub before suspending, the computer will stay suspended. You are on the right track observing that USB is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on linux mint. Tried to mess with configuration file  /proc/acpi/wakeup, but that didn't work for me for me. Basically you disable device from waking up the PC completly, which is not what you usually want. You want to be able to use device such as keyboard or mouse to wake up Pc on your command not on its own.
finally, the issue solved itself after I switch the usb port i use for keyboard dongle. after that it worked fine, so it might help you too

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1185051)

Comment: This answer gives new ideas, not only for the OP, but for others desperately searching a solution and coming to this thread. I think it is not ok to vote down this answer. It discourages people from giving helpful hints.