# Changing wake on usb

Tags: usb, mouse, suspend

My laptop keeps waking on my mouse while in my bag. I can go about disabling my wake on mouse by changing `/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1/power/wakeup` to disable.

Everything is grand, until I reboot and it reverts back to enabled.

Anyone have any thoughts to prevent that from happening?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wake up from suspend using wireless USB keyboard or mouse (for any Linux Distro)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/848698/wake-up-from-suspend-using-wireless-usb-keyboard-or-mouse-for-any-linux-distro)