# How to wake Ubuntu 20.04 from sleep with wireless mouse/keyboard?

Tags: usb, keyboard, 20.04, mouse, suspend

I've checked [Wake up from suspend using wireless USB keyboard or mouse (for any Linux Distro)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/848698/wake-up-from-suspend-using-wireless-usb-keyboard-or-mouse-for-any-linux-distro) ; its answer appears to already be applied on my PC: the string "`enabled`" is written to the file `/sys/bus/usb/devices/<device>/power/wakeup`.

```
$ grep . /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/product
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-12/product:Integrated_Webcam_HD
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-2/product:USB Receiver
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/product:xHCI Host Controller
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/product:xHCI Host Controller
```

```
$ grep . /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/wakeup
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-2/power/wakeup:enabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-4/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/power/wakeup:disabled
```

It looks like usb device `1-2` is my Logitech usb receiver, and its `wakeup` file already has the string "`enabled`". But none of 1) moving my mouse, 2) clicking mouse buttons, or 3) pressing keyboard buttons wakes Ubuntu from sleep -- only lifting the laptop lid does.

What gives? What else can be done to enable wake-from-sleep by wireless mouse/keyboard?

---

If relevant:

```
$ uname -a
Linux linuxbox 5.4.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 00:24:02 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

Mouse: Logitech Performance MX
Keyboard: Logitech K800
Connected by wireless dongle to usb port.

Comment: Does the GNOME Extension Remove Shield work for you?

Comment: @User24601 - It _installed_ okay, and didn't report any errors in Tweak UI, but appeared non-functional: when I awoke my PC from sleep (still by opening the laptop lid), the shield screen was still present.

Comment: I'm also having this problem with Bluetooth (tho also logi) on a Yoga 720.

Answer (score 3):

1. First, enter the command `lsusb`. This will show you the names of your USB devices, like this:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 058f:6362 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Card Reader/Writer
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 003: ID 413c:2010 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 413c:1003 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard Hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 413c:3016 Dell Computer Corp. Optical 5-Button Wheel Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

2. Find the name of the device you want to use to wake the computer (for example, `Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard`) and note the number next to `Bus` (example: `Bus 007`).
3. Type `sudo nano /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb7/power/wakeup` replacing the number in `usb7` with the device's `Bus` number (without the 0's in front, e.g. `Bus 007` > `usb7`).
4. Change the word `disabled` to `enabled` and save the file.

Comment: You can put these commands into /etc/rc.local ... see https://jolahde.kapsi.fi/2018/02/05/enabling-usb-keyboard-and-mouse-to-wake-up-ubuntu-from-suspension/