# Disable specific device from waking up the system

Tags: usb, wakeup

I could find similar topics but could not find an answer.

In my system (Xubuntu 20.04) `grep . /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/wakeup` only delivers this

```
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/3-13/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/3-14/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/3-5/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb3/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb4/power/wakeup:disabled
```

Full list of files in the `/sys/bus/usb/devices/3-5/power/`

```
active_duration  
async  
autosuspend  
autosuspend_delay_ms  
connected_duration  
control  
level  
persist  
runtime_active_kids  
runtime_active_time  
runtime_enabled  
runtime_status  
runtime_suspended_time  
runtime_usage  
wakeup  
wakeup_abort_count  
wakeup_active  
wakeup_active_count
wakeup_count
wakeup_expire_count
wakeup_last_time_ms
wakeup_max_time_ms
wakeup_total_time_ms
```

Yet the wireless mouse (+ 2.4GHz USB dongle) wake the system up from suspend.
Is there any way to get that specific USB port/device disabled?

The `lshw` gives me

```
          *-usbhost:0      
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.4.0-70-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@3
                logical name: usb3
                version: 5.04
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=15 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:0
                   description: Mouse
                   product: Wireless Mouse
                   vendor: Genius
                   physical id: 5
                   bus info: usb@3:5
                   version: 10.01
                   capabilities: usb-1.10
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
```

And the `lsusb -t` says

```
    /:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 5000M
    /:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/15p, 480M
        |__ Port 5: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 10: Dev 2, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
        |__ Port 10: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 10: Dev 2, If 3, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
        |__ Port 10: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 12: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=mt7601u, 480M
        |__ Port 13: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 13: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 14: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    /:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/8p, 480M
    /:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
```

But since no `/sys/bus/usb/devices` seems to be relevant I'm not sure what to configure and how.

Comment: I had a similar problem. I've got a couple of scripts to do it, but it looks like they won't work for you because USB 3-5 already shows as disabled.

Comment: @heynnema that's exactly what confuses me. because i did research the issue and ppls were suggesting finding the 'enabled' device and simply replace it w/'disabled' in the `/sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/wakeup`.
But my config shows it's 'disabled' (which i feel actually relates to a different device).

Looks like the 'wireless dongle' part is what messes stuff a bit.
I just got that wireless mouse and it started waking up my box from the 'sleep/standby' mode even on move...

Maybe a better way would be to simply power down the USB port on 'sleep'?

Comment: You could try to plug/unplug the mouse dongle and confirm which device appear/disappears in `lsusb` and `/sys/bus/usb/devices`. Maybe you've already done that.

Comment: Yes, I did that. It's that same 'USB 3-5' device. Every time the same.

Comment: Review the other parameters in /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-5/power/ to see if there's anything else that sounds like it has to do with resume/sleep.

Comment: @heynnema i dunno (sorry, i'm not an experienced Linux admin).
Just added the content of the folder to the question text (could not fit into the comment).

Comment: Just for fun, try a wired mouse, or one that doesn't use 2.4Ghz, and see if the same problem occurs. You'll have to recheck the /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/wakeup settings to make sure it's not enabled.

Comment: @heynnema the whole reason i'm asking this question is I have always used a wired USB mouse. :)  
And I never had such problems. Also, I use a USB keyboard via PS/2 adapter exactly because USB keyboard does not wake up the system from sleep/suspend.
Now I decided to give a wireless mouse a try and got this unwanted 'wakeup' effect.

Comment: I understand. However, I don't know how to fix your specific problem. My wireless Logitech mouse/dongle had the same problem, and I could see the "enabled" flag, so I could fix it. Must have something to do with your 2.4Ghz wireless dongle/mouse.

Comment: Right, potentially it's the way the 'dongle' is programmed to behave (it's showing as Genius, may be those do behave different from Logitech)

Comment: @heynnema And it looks like **potentially** there's something wrong with my OS/motherboard/whatever... Or it's an inherent problem of desktops vs laptops...

Because I just plugged it into a Dell Laptop w/Xubuntu (don't remember immediately, 18.04 or 20.04) and it worked as expected (almost) - didn't wake up the laptop on mouse move/click.

It still had to have a button clicked after laptop wakeup, but that's bearable to a degree...

Comment: Unless there's a BIOS setting that needs tweaking, I don't think it's a problem with your motherboard. Just use a wired mouse, or get yourself a Logitech wireless mouse :-)

Comment: @heynnema no, i couldn't find anything relevant in BIOS. well... I was going to try to re-install the system (since I messed up some other [irrelevant here] settings which I would like to set up from scratch) and see if it changes anything...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wake up from suspend using wireless USB keyboard or mouse (for any Linux Distro)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/848698/wake-up-from-suspend-using-wireless-usb-keyboard-or-mouse-for-any-linux-distro)

Answer (score 3):

Writing a value `disabled` instead of `enabled` into the file `/sys/bus/usb/devices/3-5/power/wakeup` is working correctly: when the value is `disabled`, a corresponding mouse or keyboard doesn't wake up the computer, but if the value is `enabled` - they wake up it. This helper script do it for a device with particular `vendorId` and `productId`:

```
#!/bin/bash
### Put it here: /usr/bin/usb-resume-control

while getopts v:p:s: flag
do
    case "${flag}" in
      v) vendor=${OPTARG};;
      p) product=${OPTARG};;
      s) state=${OPTARG};;
    esac
done
if [ -z "$vendor" -o -z "$product" ]; then
        echo -en "Usage: $0 -v vendorId -p productId -s state\nin any order, where vendorId and productId are both from [lsusb] and state can be enable or disable\n"
        exit 1;
fi
if [ -z $state ]; then
        stateTo="disabled"
fi
DEVICES=/sys/bus/usb/devices

for a in `ls $DEVICES`; do
  if [ -f "$DEVICES/$a/idVendor" -a -f "$DEVICES/$a/idProduct" ]; then
    idVendor=`cat "$DEVICES/$a/idVendor"`
    idProduct=`cat "$DEVICES/$a/idProduct"`
    if [ -f "$DEVICES/$a/product" ]; then 
      productName=`cat "$DEVICES/$a/product"`
    fi
    WAKEUPFILE="$DEVICES/$a/power/wakeup"
    if [ $idVendor = $vendor -a $idProduct = $product -a -f "$WAKEUPFILE" ]; then
      oldState=`cat "$WAKEUPFILE"`
      echo "$state" > "$WAKEUPFILE"
      newState=`cat "$WAKEUPFILE"`
      echo Bus-port:$a vendor=$idVendor product=$idProduct name=$productName WakeUp: old=$oldState new=$newState
    fi
  fi
done
```

To automate process create a `systemd` unit file `/etc/systemd/system/control-usb-wakeup-mouse.service` with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Control wakeup of USB device before sleep so they will or not resume the computer
Before=sleep.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/usb-resume-control -v 045e -p 0745 -s disabled
StandardOutput=journal

[Install]
WantedBy=sleep.target
```

Update vendorId and productId to your USB device (see output of `lsusb`). After that run those commands against a unit:

```
chmod 755 /etc/systemd/system/control-usb-wakeup-mouse.service
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable control-usb-wakeup-mouse.service
```

Now the device mentioned cannot wake up the computer after sleep.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was inspired by your solution to write a little tool to make this process easier for daily use and multiple devices: https://github.com/bvobart/usb-wakeup-control

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there are BIOS settings for USB ports to enable/disable power during suspend and/or enable/disable wakeup.

But you may also need to disable wakeup for the relevant USB controllers/hubs. Try this:

`cat /proc/acpi/wakeup`

I actually don't know how to confirm the device names here is the device you want as the names listed here are different to what you see elsewhere but in my case my USB devices are EHC1, EHC2 and XHC

You can toggle between enabled and disabled by doing for example:

```
sudo -s
echo XHC > /proc/acpi/wakeup
exit
```

But I am not sure it's a permanent change. I am not sure on the best way to make it permanent, I just made an executable script to echo the commands I needed and added it to roots crontab like:

`@reboot /etc/my_script`

Comment: The problem with the `/proc/acpi/wakeup` is it will disable the whole controller.
So that no other USB device will wake up the box (like my USB keyboard).
I was looking for a way to disable precise device.

I checked my BIOS setting today. There's no such setting.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old but I had issues with this too and other solutions did not work. I have found a much simpler solution to this problem and hope it helps.

What **uglic** says about writing the value **disabled** instead of **enabled** into the file `/sys/bus/usb/devices/3-5/power/wakeup` works correctly is true. Though just to be clear this only works up until you reboot, at that point it is enabled again.

A quick and dirty way to set disabled "permanently" is to simply echo **disabled** into the **/*/power/wakeup file from the */etc/rc.local* file.

```
echo disabled > /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-5/power/wakeup
```

Something like that before the last line in the */etc/rc.local* file should do the trick.