# 20.04 Wakeup from wireless keyboard/mouse only works with AC power

Tags: keyboard, suspend, mouse, battery, wakeup

Using Ubuntu 20.04
Recently I bought an external monitor to help my eyes. I have 14" FHD laptop.
All was good, until I realized that if I was on battery power and laptop was suspended, it will not wake up from wireless USB keyboard/mouse.
I landed up here
[Wake up from suspend using wireless USB keyboard or mouse (for any Linux Distro)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/848698/wake-up-from-suspend-using-wireless-usb-keyboard-or-mouse-for-any-linux-distro)

But that did not help when laptop was sleeping on battery.

can anyone please help me with this.

NOTE: I suspend my laptop and switch off power before going to bed.