# Trying to get my mouse to wakup my pc after sleep. Device listed in lsusb but not in grep wakeup command

Tags: usb, keyboard, suspend, mouse, power-management

I am trying to get my mouse to wake up the pc after sleep. I went through the post here [Wake up from suspend using wireless USB keyboard or mouse (for any Linux Distro)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/848698/wake-up-from-suspend-using-wireless-usb-keyboard-or-mouse-for-any-linux-distro). But no luck. But i noticed that for some reason my device is not listed in when I do `grep . /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/wakeup`. I get the following output:

```
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-2/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/3-1/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/3-3/power/wakeup:enabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb3/power/wakeup:enabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb4/power/wakeup:disabled
```

But when I do `lsusb` I get the following:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c53d Logitech, Inc. USB Receiver
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c537 Logitech, Inc. Cordless Mouse Receiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 090c:1000 Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) Flash Drive
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1462:7c56 Micro Star International MYSTIC LIGHT 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

As you can see my device 3-2 is not listed in the `grep . /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/wakeup` but it is listed in `lsusb`. I looked in the `/sys/bus/usb/devices/` folder and there is no folder for 3-1. The mouse is working it just won't wake up the pc from sleep.

Can anyone shine some light on this for me and maybe point me in the right direction on how to get my mouse to wakup my pc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/848699/1546838) works for me. Just with few mods added (and 21.04 Ubuntu version considered).

In order to define the wakeup command from a device, you need to take note about that:

- The previous MB WakeUp config check state 
   (Ignored in your case, it's looks like autodetected).
- The power management actions
   (Configured in Battery icon next to clock).
   You have to check if the sleep/suspend mode is triggered by some situations.
- The USB Assigned number:
   (Your case is USB N°3 (Or Bus 3)).

Let's start:

Create a [bash script file](https://linuxhandbook.com/run-shell-script/) for auto select this port as wakeup and put them in the autostart config section (as app) **Note: Do this only for this time**
 **copy/paste**

> #!/bin/bash
> echo enabled > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb3/power/wakeup

Edit: also check if your devices selectively turns off usb devices

Comment: usb3 is already enabled. Check the results of `grep . /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/wakeup` Its not the usb itself that I need to enable its the device 2 on bus 3. And I already tried the solution you linked to. I linked to it in my question.