# Macbook screen turns back on after suspend

Tags: 16.04, suspend, screen, macbook

I decided to switch to Ubuntu from mac os and it mostly works fine, but one problem appeared:

When I press 'Suspend' or close the lid of my macbook, the screen turns black (like it should) and after around 3-5 seconds the **screen turns on again** with the login screen.

I'm sorry if anyone already asked this question, but I didn't find a similar problem with a google search.

Edit: Model Number is A 1502 EMC 2835

Comment: as root run:  dmidecode  |grep -i macbook so we have more details about your specific hardware

Comment: @Arronical Please don't change the title when you haven't read my question yet. Everything was correct. [link](http://askubuntu.com/revisions/895849/5)

Comment: @tomodachi  Here it is: Product Name: MacBookPro12,1
 Family: MacBook Pro
 Version: MacBookPro12,1

Comment: Sorry @Jeb, looks like I was a bit hasty there!

Comment: @Arronical In the end everything worked out, so no problem!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are effected by [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1507472) which appears to effect kernels 4.2 - 4.4 I suggest that you subscribe to the bug so that you can be notified of progress and the developers have a better idea of the impact it's having. As touched on by [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/898579/225694) by [user 1783630](https://askubuntu.com/users/601772/user1783630) According to the author of the bug a functional workaround is to Disable XHC1 prior to sleeping by issuing the command

`echo XHC1 > /proc/acpi/wakeup`

However, the current content of /proc/acpi/wakeup in my 16.04 system is a bit more complex than that consisting of 4 columns of info covering Device, S-state, status, and sysfs node so I'm not convinced this is the way to go with Ubuntu. The bug has already been confirmed and triaged so hopefully this will be resolved with a newer kernel.

**Edit:** This [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148481/how-do-i-prevent-immediate-wake-up-from-suspend-and-or-hibernation) also has some good answers that you may be able to modify to fit your circumstances

Source:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1507472

Comment: Thanks you very much! You initial solution didn't work, because i needed to disable something else. The link you provided me helped.

Comment: @Jeb I'm glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 4):

From the Arch Wiki entry for your model:

[It may be necessary to disable USB's wakeup ability by by echoing 'XHC1' to '/proc/acpi/wakeup' in order to prevent immediate wakeup on suspend.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MacBookPro11,x#Screen_backlight)

Once you tried it, you can put the line into your `/etc/rc.local` file in order for it to be executed on every boot.