# How to prevent network manager from waking up laptop?

Tags: suspend, power-management

Installed 18.04LTS with update from 16.04 on Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga 12.
Suspend is always been an issue, did never work well. In 16.04 with kernel 4.10 is was OK.
Upgraded to 18.04 and again, no suspend. Computer suspends fine, but is woken up immediately after. Did a syslog and is showed sleep status OK and in same second a wake up request from network manager.
How can I solve this?
Everything else is working fine. (currently on Kernel 4.15.13), updated BIOS to 1.37 and all other updates done.
Thx!

Comment: Managed sort of a solution with this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/148481/how-do-i-prevent-immediate-wake-up-from-suspend-and-or-hibernation Nothing to do with the network manager at all? -confused-

Comment: Can you answer your own question? That will give it some value for others :)

Comment: Please answer before the question is voted off-topic as "Problem went away all by itself"

Comment: I disabled the wake up possibility of usb3 as per document in link above. On My system iT was XHC. I Found a demand of netwerk manager to wake up the system in syslog, nut I think that was a mistake.