# How to stop keystrokes from switching on my hibernating PC?

Tags: usb, keyboard, power-management, hibernate

I have hibernation enabled on my Ubuntu PC and it works pretty well. One thing that turns me off though is that my hibernating PC gets turned on on a keystroke. I just want to turn it back on by pressing the POWER button ONLY. I tried to disable it from the BIOS settings but could not seem to find anything relevant... I am using a USB keyboard BTW, the problem may be related to that. Any solutions?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1220105/15811 should have all you need.

Comment: Thanks, apparently that did the job.