# How to find a device based on its device ID

Tags: suspend, device-name

Recently I had a problem that one of the USB ports was stopping Ubuntu 20.04 from suspending. It was suspending, but in a split of the second started again.

I found in several posts ([1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148481/how-do-i-prevent-immediate-wake-up-from-suspend-and-or-hibernation), [2](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/how-to-disable-usb-wake-from-suspend/23163/2), [3](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/power-management-acpi-wake-up-settings/17344)) that it is possible to fix this by disabling a device in `/proc/acpi/wakeup`, but how to find which device stands behind each device code was not mentioned.

```
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
PEG0      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:01.0
PEGP      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:01:00.0
LID0      S3    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0D:01
RP01      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP02      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP03      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP04      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP05      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1c.0
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP06      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP07      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1c.6
PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:03:00.0
RP08      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1c.7
PXSX      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:04:00.0
GLAN      S4    *disabled
EHC1      S3    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1d.0
EHC2      S3    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1a.0
XHC   S3    *disabled  pci:0000:00:14.0
TPD4      S4    *disabled
TPD7      S0    *disabled
TPD8      S0    *disabled
HDEF      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1b.0
```

For me, problematic was `EHC2` which is USB3.0 (`echo EHC2 | sudo tee  /proc/acpi/wakeup`), but I found out about it after several trials of disable-suspend operations.

**How can I find out what device is meant by these 3-4 character device IDs?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device codes are vendor specific and are written in the DSDT (Differentiated System Description Table) inside the BIOS/UEFI. That said, there are some commonalities between the different manufacturers:

| Name | Device |
| --- | --- |
| EHCx / USBx | USB 2.0 (EHCI) chip |
| GLAN | Gigabit Ethernet |
| LID | Laptop lid |
| PEGx | PCI Express for Graphics slot #x |
| PS2K | PS/2 keyboard |
| PS2M | PS/2 mouse |
| PWRB / PBTN | Power button |
| RP0x / EXPx | PCIE slot #x (aka PCI Express Root Port #x) |
| XHC | USB 3.0 (XHCI) chip |

Any device not matching these patterns would need to be looked up in the technical documentation for the motherboard.